# more readable format for sql commands in c

Tags: sql, c

Any suggestions on a more readable way to format a long mysql insert command in C. I think it would help if the string could be broken down into multiple lines?

```
char sqlcmd[1000];
snprintf(sqlcmd, "INSERT INTO cdrs(col1,col2,col3,col2,col4,col6,col5,col7,col9,col8,col10,col12,col11,col13,col15,col14,col16,col18,col17,col19,col21,col20,col22,col24,col23,col25,col27,col26,col28,col30,col29,col31,col33,col32,col34 VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')", one,two,three,four,one,two,three,four,one,two,three,four,one,two,three,four,one ,two,three,four,one,two,three,four,one,two,three,four,one ,two,three,four,one,two,three);
```

Comment: I would suggest learning about prepared statements and placeholders (or variable binding ... whatever it is the API you're using calls it).

Answer (score 3):

You can split up a string in C into multiple double-quoted pieces just by putting whitespace between them. The three strings here are exactly equivalent:

```
"hello world"
"hello" " world"
"hel" "lo " "wor" "ld"
```

Whitespace includes newlines, so in your case you could:

```
snprintf(sqlcmd, "INSERT INTO cdrs("
                    "col1, col2, col3, ..."
                 ") values ("
                 // etc
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the phases when compiling C sources is to run the code through a "preprocessor" that will expand macros, perform stringification tasks, and concatenate adjacent strings. This lets you re-write the code like this:

```
snprintf(sqlcmd, "INSERT INTO cdrs(col1,col2,col3,col2,col4,col6,col5,"
                              "col7,col9,col8,col10,col12,col11,col13,"
                              "col15,col14,col16,col18,col17,col19,col21,"
                              /* .. and so on .. */
                              "'%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')",
                              one,two,three,four,one,two,
                              three,four,one,two,three,four,
                              /* .. and so on .. */
                              one,two,three,four,one,two,three);
```

You can line up the columns with the variables to make the variable -> column mapping more obvious. Since these are just noisy names, I haven't bothered, but the result would be much more pleasing when applied with actual column and variable names.

Answer (score 1):

It can be broken down in multiple lines. The preprocessor does "string joining" in one of its phases.

```
char sqlcmd[1000];
snprintf(sqlcmd, "INSERT INTO cdrs(col1, col2, col3, col2, col4, col6, col5, col7, "
                 "col9, col8, col10, col12, col11, col13, col15, col14, col16, "
                 "col18, col17, col19, col21, col20, col22, col24, col23, col25, "
                 "col27, col26, col28, col30, col29, col31, col33, col32, col34 "
                 "VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', "
                 "'%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', "
                 "'%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', "
                 "'%s', '%s', '%s', '%s','%s')",
                one, two, three, four, one, two, three, four, one, two, three,
                four, one, two, three, four, one, two, three, four, one, two,
                three, four, one, two, three, four, one, two, three, four,
                one, two, three);
```

Also, you're missing a parentheses before VALUES :)

Answer (score 1):

The string in C can be broken into multiple lines, e.g:

```
snprintf(sqlcmd, "INSERT INTO cdrs("
"col1,col2,col3,col2,col4,"
"col6,col5,col7,col9,col8,"
"col10,col12,col11,col13,"
"col15,col14,col16,col18,"
"col17,col19,col21,col20,"
"col22,col24,col23,col25,"
"col27,col26,col28,col30,"
"col29,col31,col33,col32,col34"
"VALUES("         
"'%s','%s','%s','%s',"
"'%s','%s','%s','%s',"
"'%s','%s','%s','%s',"
"'%s','%s','%s','%s',"
"'%s','%s','%s','%s',"
"'%s','%s','%s','%s',"
"'%s','%s','%s','%s',"
"'%s','%s','%s','%s',"
"'%s','%s')",    
one,two,three,four,
one,two,three,four,
one,two,three,four,
one,two,three,four,
one,two,three,four,
one,two,three,four,
one,two,three,four,
one,two,three,four,
one,two,three);
```

In fact a string declared as below is equivalent of `"one two three"`:

```
const char* msg = "one " "two " "three";
```